# How to get downloaded file size in android

Tags: android, file

i don't know how to get total file size. this gives me -1 always

```
double totalSize = 0;
URL url = new URL(Constants.AUDIOURL+kid+".mp3");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
totalSize = (double)urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Comment: are you getting contentLength??

Comment: yes i am getting content length but it is always -1

Comment: than you need to add setContentLength() from the server side to get your length over here.

Answer (score 4):

Please find below code snippet. It works for your situation.

```
try{
 URL uri = new URL(Constants.AUDIOURL+kid+".mp3");
 URLConnection urlconnection = uri.openConnection();
 urlconnection .connect();
 String fileLengthStr = urlconnection .getHeaderField("content-length");
 Log.d("File Size", fileLengthStr );     
}
catch(Exception exception){
 exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it gives this error   java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: Am getting this File Size: 957134 for the URL: http://www.hdwallpapersfreedownload.com/uploads/large/cartoons/tom-and-jerry-best-friends-free-hd-wallpaper.jpg without any errror. Please provide your url.

Answer (score 0):

i solved by this code

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```